# How can I check if a domain is malicious?

Tags: malware, dns-domain, domain

I have started to look for domain names inside my traffic. So I am interested to identify which one is malicious or doing some malicious acitivites.

I know by looking at online web-services such as `virus total` or `url void` I can get a general idea about domains or by looking at registration information but these still wont help me to say by a level of certainty that this domain is malicious.

So my question is that if you got a domain name what would be your work flow to manually analyze the domain and figure out if it is malicious or not or in more detail identify the malware family related to that domain.

Comment: Can you be more specific in which infrastructure you are trying to analyze domains?

Comment: I think services like the ones you mention is your best bet here.

Comment: I am talking at the point of a company the security is important part of their company.. So it is important to identify domains are malicious or not